# char* and a char[] array error

Tags: c++, class, char

I am trying to create a class for a game I am making for my highschool c++ class. All of my set functions are not working. I will post an example tailored just to show one(I get the same error for all of them). Here is the prob:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class room {

public:

    void set_desk(char *);
    char get_desk();

private:

char desk[16];

}

int main {

room room1;
room1.set_desk("a desk");

cout << room1.get_desk();
return(0);
}
void room::set_desk(char *a){
     room::desk = *a;
}
char room::get_desk(){
     return(room::desk);
}
```

So when I try to compile this, I get this error: "In member function void room::set_desk(char *)': error: incompatible types in assignment of char to char[16]" and also this error: "In member function char room::get_desk(): error: invalid conversion from char* to char".

I need the char to have an array of 16, but the errors are gone if I remove the [16] from `char desk[16];`

Comment: Why don't you use `std::string`?

Comment: Assigning a `char*` to `char[]` can't be done like that, you want to be using `strcpy`/`strncpy` or change your `desk` to be a pointer, which would be in all likelihood a really bad idea, or like GWW says, switch to using `std::string` if you're using C++.

Comment: Use `std::string`. Seriously. Don't pretend you're "learning C++" if you insist on mucking around with raw pointers and char arrays. That's not C++.

Comment: It *is* C++, but I agree he should use `std::string` here.

Answer (score 6):

You can't assign pointers to arrays like that. Here's one way to get it to work.

```
void room::set_desk(char *a){

    if (strlen(a) >= sizeof(desk)){
        //  Internal buffer is not large enough. Handle error.
    }

    strcpy(desk,a);
}
char* room::get_desk(){
     return desk;
}
```

*However, you're probably better off using **strings** or **vectors** in C++ instead of char arrays and pointers.*

*You're also missing a semicolon after the class definition.

Here's a more C++-like approach:

```
class room {

public:

    void set_desk(string);
    string get_desk();

private:

    string desk;

};

void room::set_desk(const string &a){
     desk = a;
}
string room::get_desk(){
     return desk;
}

int main {

    room room1;
    room1.set_desk("a desk");

    cout << room1.get_desk();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see. My c++ teacher always tells me to use char arrays. I do have one other question, though. I also use char arrays so that I can analyze user input one letter at a time. Is there a way to do that with a string? If not, I could always use a string compare function.

Comment: Yes, you can access individual characters in a string the same way you do with arrays (using `[]`). If you have `string str = "abc";`, then `str[0]` will give the first letter (`a`), `str[1]` will give the second, etc...

Comment: Does your C++ teacher give you a *reason* for using char arrays? If not, how will you know when *not* to use them?

Comment: @user1024742: By the sound of it, the best you could do for your C++ education is to stop listening to that teacher and instead read a good book!

Comment: The problem with that `memcpy` call is that you're over-reading any string less than `strlen` 15.  If the allocated memory is the `strlen` + 1, I believe that's undefined behavior.  It would be better to use `strncat` or just `strcpy` with a `strlen` check.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: You're right, I just replaced it with `strncpy`.

Comment: @Mysticial throw the guy a sizeof(desk) rather than that magic number while you're at it....

Comment: @Mystical, there's a reason I didn't say that.  It wastes time padding NULs, but ironically doesn't NUL-terminate if the source `strlen` is greater than or equal to the third parameter.  If you use `strncpy`, you need to NUL-terminate it yourself.

Comment: Understood and fixed... Yet another reason why to not mess directly `char` arrays in C++ when there's `string`.

Comment: If you use sizeof(desk)-1 and initialize the reserved character to null, you're fine with strncpy

Comment: Worst case, assign null to desk[sizeof(desk)-1] after the strncpy for safety.  Faster than strlen on the source just to compensate for strncpy

Comment: @user1024742: Use Mysticial's strcpy suggestion. Your teacher is right to encourage you to fiddle about with arrays and pointers. Once you're familiar with the low-level arrays and pointers of C, you'll understand why the higher-level C++ features like std::string are useful, and when to employ them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to prefix every reference to desk with room::

strncpy(desk,a,sizeof(desk)-1);

desk[sizeof(desk)-1] = 0;

Use the above so you can safely change the size of desk.

Change the return type of your getter to char*

Comment: See my comment to Mystical's answer for why this is broken.

Comment: Fixed by ensuring there is always a null